# Value does not remain selected on focus

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select values of an input on focus. It initially works but it doesn't hold the value. I want the value to remain selected until the user takes another action.

Here is my script:

```
$('.myclass1').focus(
function ()
{
  this.select() 
});
$('.myclass3').focus(
function ()
{
  this.select() 
});
$('.myclass3').focus(
function ()
{
  this.select() 
});
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dan_vitch/c4YGn/1/.

When I select the input that holds a value. The value gets highlighted initially, doesn't remain selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `.focus` with `.mouseup` at every occurrence.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/c4YGn/2/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach:

```
var timeoutIndex = 0;

$('.dateSpinMonth,.dateSpinDay,.dateSpinYear').bind('focus keyup mouseup', function () {
    var that = this;
    clearTimeout(timeoutIndex);
    timeoutIndex = setTimeout(function() { that.select(); }, 250);
});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/c4YGn/3/)